# Layout of user area on top bar broken on Stack Overflow Contests page

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, design

On the page for Stack Overflow Contests (https://contests.stackoverflow.com/), the top bar is broken. The issue could potentially be due to the missing search bar.

Screenshot:

[image]

I haven't seen this happen on any other pages.

Comment: For me eveything seems right except font color and duplicates in badges area: https://i.imgur.com/QrTMcfX.png It might that someone edits this part of header on the air.

Comment: @V.7: Note the duplicated reputation and the text additional texts "xx gold/silver/bronze badges". These are normally not present.

Comment: repro-ed on Chrome 78, Win10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed up when we gave Contests and Winter Bash some .NET Core overhaul loving late last year. The proper includes (it was missing one of the stylesheets) is resolved now!

Answer (score -2):

Looks like some programmer forgot to remove/hide unecessary elements from this header element, thus scrollbar shows up because of overflow property or such:

[image: img_1]

Removing those highlighted above helps via adding `span.v-visible-sr {display: none;}` into stylesheet. For example, you might want to use some extension like [User JavaScript and CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld) to achieve this, which would remove this unecessary hightlighted text below:

[image: img_2]

Comment: Those elements are meant to be used by screen readers (hence the "sr" in the class). They are actually present on all pages, so it looks like they simply forgot to include the needed CSS to hide them. But they are indeed the cause.

Comment: Just because it's Meta doesn't mean it's suddenly OK to post images of code.